# Некорректно отрабатывает FIND_IN_SET с переменной

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с полями

```
id | name | pos
```

По умолчанию у всех полей `pos` значение 0. Хочу проставить во все строки рандомные значения от 1 до `COUNT` строк в таблице:

```
SET @ids := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY RAND()) FROM `test666`) ;
SET @ids_str := (SELECT CONCAT('"', @ids, '"'));
SET @ids_str_result = (SELECT @ids_str);


UPDATE test666 SET pos = FIND_IN_SET(id, @ids_str_result);
```

В итоге почему-то всегда два каких-нибудь значения остаются с нулём.

Хотя если написать запрос

```
SELECT @ids_str_result;
```

то выведет корректно строку со **всеми** идентификаторами.

В чём может быть проблема?

P.S. попытался сделать пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d797/4, но кажется песочница не умеет в переменные...

Comment: так он потеряет два идентификатора, которые оказались около кавычек. он же сравнивает _строки_ разделенные запятыми, а вы зачем то к началу и концу добавляете кавычки, вот он и пытается найти `"81` вместо просто `81`

Comment: @Mike разве? мы еще в прошлом вопросе выяснили что `find_in_set` это вроде как цельная строка))... и в [доках](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html) написано `'a,b,c,d'`.... или я что-то не понял? :-/  ........ блин.... я делал вот так `SET @ids := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY RAND()) FROM \`test666\`) ; UPDATE test666 SET pos = FIND_IN_SET(id, @ids);` и не получалось....честно...поэтому и начал такие выкрутасы.... пришел домой - получилось :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу проставить во все строки рандомные значения от 1 до COUNT строк в таблице

```
SET @counter := 0;

UPDATE test666 
SET pos = (@counter := 1 + @counter)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Answer (score 1):

Итак, согласно [докам](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html) `FIND_IN_SET` вторым параметром принимает строку, состоящую из подстрок, разделенных символами `,`. Пример:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

После запроса:

```
SET @ids := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY RAND()) FROM `table`);
```

в переменной `@ids` **уже** будет содержаться **строка** с рандомными номерами через запятую, поэтому при конкатенации `SET @ids_str := (SELECT CONCAT('"', @ids, '"'));` получается строка для выборки следующего вида:

```
"10,18,17,21,2,11,8,19,1,13,7,15,5,16,20,6,12,4,9,3,14,22"
```

при которой `FIND_IN_SET` будет искать совпадения так: **"10**, 18, 17, 21, 2,... , 14, **22"**, т.е. получается, что первый и последний элементы будут искаться вкупе с кавычкой. Конечно же таких элементов нет и в итоге два значения всегда сохраняют ноль.

В итоге достаточно написать:

```
SET @ids := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY RAND()) FROM `table`);
UPDATE `table` SET pos = FIND_IN_SET(id, @ids);
```

Либо так, как написал в своем ответе **@Akina**